# Limitations in number of files and filegroups in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that SQL Server database must have only one primary file ".mdf", but can consists few additional database files, named secondary files or ".ndf".

Is there any limitations in number of additional secondary files, or log files?

How many filegroups can one database have?

Comment: If you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Ask just for educational purpose, I am not really go into trouble :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server supports 32,767 Files/FileGroups per database for both x86 and x64 installations.

You can find maximum capacity specifications here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. You should add links as reference, but always quote the most relevant parts from it in you answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer